# Multiple connections for Embedded Databases

Tags: h2, derby, embedded-database

I'm working with an `H2` database in `embedded` mode and I came up with this quote in `H2` documentation ([here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases)).

> In embedded mode, an application opens a database from within the same
>   JVM using JDBC.

In `Derby` documentation ([here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/devguide/cdevdvlp96597.html)), I came up with this.

> If you use the embedded driver, two separate instances of Derby cannot
>   access the same database. If a Derby instance attempts to access a
>   running database, an error message appears, and a stack trace appears
>   in the derby.log file. If you want more than one Derby instance to be
>   able to access the same database, you can use the Network Server.

I would really appreciate if someone can elaborate on **why** is that only the *same* JVM can access the database in embedded mode.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, elaborate on the H2 behavior? Or elaborate on the Derby behavior? Or just elaborate on database concurrency control in general?

Comment: Can you explain it generally (Third option you mentioned) ? Thank you